# Simple chat app with Nodejs + Socket.IO + Android Kotlin

Tags: android, node.js, kotlin, socket.io

I got some errors in my app. In client, it has 1 activity and inside it are a button + a text edit and a recycler view. And everybody can chat in there. But something errors and i dont know how to fix it. I tested with 2 emulator, and when i send the message in the emulator 1, then the message was appear in emulator 2 ( sometime in emulator 1 ) many times even thought i just send the message 1 times. This is source code :

Server Nodejs and Socket.IO :

```
const express = require('express')
const socketIO = require('socket.io')

const app = express()
const server = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = socketIO(server)

io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
    const id = socket.id
    socket.on('id', () => {
        io.emit('id',id)
    })
    console.log(`${id} client connected`);
    socket.on('sendMessage', (data) => {
        console.log(`Message received from client: ${data}`);
        io.emit('receiveMessage',data)
    })

})

server.listen(3000,() => {
    console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
})
```

MessageAdapter.kt

```
   class MessageAdapter(private val messages : MutableList<Message>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(){
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when(viewType){
            MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND -> MessageSendViewHolder(SendMessageBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false
            ))

            else -> MessageReceiveViewHolder(ReceiveMessageBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false
            ))
        }
    }

    fun addMessage(message: Message){
        messages.add(message)
        notifyItemChanged(messages.size - 1)
    }
    
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return messages.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if(getItemViewType(position) == MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND){
            (holder as MessageSendViewHolder).bind(messages[position])
        } else {
            (holder as MessageReceiveViewHolder).bind(messages[position])
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (messages[position].messageType == TypeMessage.TRUE) MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND else MESSAGE_TYPE_RECEIVE
    }



    class MessageSendViewHolder(private val binding : SendMessageBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
        fun bind(data : Message){
            binding.sendMessage.text = data.message
        }
    }

    class MessageReceiveViewHolder(private val binding : ReceiveMessageBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
        fun bind(data: Message){
            binding.receiveMessage.text = data.message
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND = 1
        private const val MESSAGE_TYPE_RECEIVE = 0
    }
}
```

Message.kt :

```
data class Message(
    val message : String,
    val messageType : TypeMessage
)

enum class TypeMessage{
    TRUE,FALSE
}
```

Resource.kt

```
sealed class Resource<T> {
    class Success<T>(val data: T? = null) : Resource<T>()

    class Error<T> (val data : T? = null) : Resource<T>()
}
```

MainViewModel.kt

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _textLiveData = MutableLiveData<Resource<Message>>()
    val textLiveData get() = _textLiveData
    private lateinit var id2 : String
    private lateinit var socket : Socket
    init {
        try {
            socket = IO.socket("https://d626-2402-800-6273-7a35-417e-5403-ee2-a273.ngrok-free.app")
        } catch (_: Exception) {
        }

        socket.connect()
        socket.emit("id")

        socket.on("id"){args->
            if(args[0] != null){
                var id = args[0] as String
                id2 = id
            }
        }
    }

    fun sendMessage(msg : String){
        socket.emit("sendMessage",msg)
        socket.on("receiveMessage"){args->
            if(args[0] != null){
                val data = args[0] as String
                if(id2 == socket.id()){
                    _textLiveData.postValue(Resource.Success(Message(data,TypeMessage.TRUE)))
                } else {
                    _textLiveData.postValue(Resource.Error(Message(data,TypeMessage.FALSE)))
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

MainActivity.kt :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var viewModel : MainViewModel
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[MainViewModel::class.java]

        val messageAdapter = MessageAdapter(mutableListOf())
        binding.rvChat.apply {
            adapter = messageAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
        }

        binding.imageButton.setOnClickListener{
            val message = binding.editTextText.text.toString()
            viewModel.sendMessage(message)
            binding.editTextText.text.clear()
        }
        viewModel.textLiveData.observe(this){resource->
            when(resource){
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    resource.data?.let {
                        messageAdapter.addMessage(it)
                    }
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    resource.data?.let {
                        messageAdapter.addMessage(it)
                    }
                }
                else -> {}

            }
        }
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }

}
```